# SSRS conditional textbox in header if any rows contain a certain value

Tags: reporting-services

I need to show a warning in at the top of a report if there are any rows with a 0 in a certain column.

I could create a new data set with its own query, but the joins required are expensive.

I tried creating a report value and in the column that controls it, I used this expression:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!state.Value)=0, Variables!hasPreProduction.SetValue(1), "0")
```

I know it is wrong because `Variables!hasPreProduction.SetValue(1)` is underlined red.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean Report Variable not "report value"? The values of these are calculated once per report, based on the expression in their definition.  You cannot push values into them.

I would use code for this, e.g. define a counter variable and a functions to add to it and return its value e.g.

```
Dim Counter As Integer

Function AddToCounter ( ByVal AddValue As Integer )

Counter = Counter + AddValue

End Function

Function GetCounter () As Integer

GetCounter = Counter

End Function
```

Then the expression on the row would call that function e.g.

`=Code.AddToCounter(IIf(Sum(Fields!state.Value)=0, 1, 0))`

Finally the textbox at the top of the report would get the value e.g.

`=Iif ( Code.GetCounter() > 0 , "Zeros Detected" , "No Zeros Detected" )`